# There's a good method to create a tilemap from an ascii matrix?

Tags: image-processing

The idea is simple, but the execution is bothering me.
I've created a small random dungeon generator that create a grid like this:

```
000001
000111
000111
001101
011101
011111
```

This is a sample 6x6 dungeon where 0 is a wall and 1 is an open path.

The conversion from this to some sort of tile id map is simple, and trivial, but creating the image itself is the hard part.

I want to know if there's a lib, or method to achieve that. If not, then what would you do?

This is not part of a game, and only a dungeon generator for DND. Any language is OK, but the generator was made in Go.

Comment: please clarify. why is this a challenge to you? where exactly is the problem? please review [ask] and [mre]. show your attempts. "proof of work".

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz This was more of a concept question. I was asking about a well known method to create a tiled image using a matrix as it's source. My problem is that I don't know many libraries to work with images, but I assumed that there was some lib to to that for me and I wanted to know if that's true.

Comment: asking for recommendations is off-topic, according to the rules. please review [ask] and [help/on-topic]. usually people let that slide when the question shows research effort.

Answer (score 0):

I kind of managed to get a solution, but it will be a Python only.
Using PIL I can make a mosaic with tile images and create the map. It's not a solid solution made from scratch but it can do the Job.

I'm still open for another approach.
My solution is this method here:

```
    matrix = np.loadtxt(input_file, usecols=range(matrix_square), dtype=int)

tiles = []

for file in glob.glob("./tiles/*"):
    im = Image.open(file)
    tiles.append(im)

output = Image.new('RGB', (image_width,image_height))

for i in range(matrix_width):
    for j in range(matrix_height):
        x,y = i*tile_size,j*tile_size
        index = matrix[j][i]
        output.paste(tiles[index],(x,y))

output.save(output_file)
```

The matrix_square is the matrix dimensions (as a square). I'm still working on a better solution, but this is working fine for me.
You need to change the tile_size to match the tile resolution that you're using.

[This is a generated dungeon with this method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cfUhW.png)

The tiles are bad, but the grid is fine enough.

Comment: Feel free to put your solution here in your answer, it can potentially help others who have the same problem:)

Comment: you've been given two other approaches (answers). if they don't do it for you, perhaps comment on them.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz They work well. The best way may be the one that the dev is more familiarized

Answer (score 0):

You can use OpenCV for this task. Probably PIL can do the same, don't have exp with it.

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

data_list = [
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
    [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
    [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
    [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1],
    [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1],
    [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
]

arr = np.array(data_list, dtype=np.uint8) * 255
arr = cv2.resize(arr, (0, 0), fx=50, fy=50, interpolation=cv2.INTER_NEAREST)
cv2.imshow("img", arr)
cv2.waitKey()

# or you can save on disk
cv2.imwrite("img.png", arr)
```

Comment: that's merely resizing... _not_ dealing with tiles at all.

Answer (score 0):

use **[`np.block()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.block.html)**

```py
# a bunch of sprites/images, all the same size
# load them however you like
tiles = [...]

data_list = [
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
    [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
    [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
    [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1],
    [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1],
    [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
]

picture = np.block([
    [tiles[k] for k in row]
    for row in data_list
])
```

Or, if you use *any* kind of game engine, or something even more trivial, like SDL/PyGame, **simply "blit" each tile**.

PIL, as you found out, is perfectly capable of *blitting* one image (tile) onto another (whole map).